# How to response non-latin characters in AWS lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

### Update Oct 12:

The issue is fixed now. See [this post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=191275) in aws forum for details.

---

I wrote a nodejs function simply respond with some Chinese characters. But it respond with wrong characters.

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    context.succeed('Hello 世界!');
};
```

The function result becomes:

```
"Hello ������������!"
```

I came across this problem when I wrote a function to parse some Chinese websites and retrieve their page titles. I manage to convert them into utf-8 (I used needle for the request), and console.log(title) correctly display those Chinese characters. But the result from context.succeed() shows up like the example above. What should I do to deal with these non-latin characters when responding the result?

Comment: Are you using this in combination with `API Gateway`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**From AWS Support (August 10, 2015):**

> Thank you for reaching out AWS Support with your question about
>   Lambda and UTF-8.
>
> We are presently researching this issue as other customers have
>   brought this to our attention. There is no eta on when this will be
>   resolved or if this is something we can resolve.

Answer (score 1):

As in [AWS Documentation - Programming Model (Node.js)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/programming-model.html#programming-model-context-object-succeed):

> Indicates the Lambda function execution and all callbacks completed
>   successfully. Here's the general syntax:
>
> ```
> context.succeed (Object result);
> ```
>
> where
>
> Object `result` – provides the result of the function execution. The
>   result provided must be `JSON.stringify` compatible. This parameter is
>   optional. You can call this method without any parameters (`succeed()`)
>   or pass a `null` value (`succeed(null)`). If AWS Lambda fails to stringify
>   or encounters another error, an unhandled error is thrown, with the
>   `X-Amz-Function-Error` response header set to Unhandled.

So, you can't get the result like this:

```
Hello 世界!
```

Because, the string `Hello 世界!` will be encoded as JSON. So, it will return:

```
"Hello 世界!"
```

If you see in the browser using AWS Lambda Console:

```
"Hello ������!"
```

[image: Hex view of result]

Actually it's a **valid JSON**, you just need to **decode** it first and then process it.

Try to run this:

```
exports.handler = function (event, context) {
  var jsonStr = JSON.stringify('Hello 世界!');
  console.log(jsonStr);
  console.log(JSON.parse(jsonStr));
  context.succeed('Hello 世界!');
};
```

The log result will be:

```
2015-08-07T12:49:54.888Z    12345678-90ab-cdef-1234-567890abcdef    "Hello 世界!"
2015-08-07T12:49:54.889Z    12345678-90ab-cdef-1234-567890abcdef    Hello 世界!
```

After you decode it, you can get back your original string.